# Formatting output csv files

Tags: python, text, formatting

Could I please get some help on the following problem. I can't seem to spot where I have gone wrong in my code. I have 2 output csv files from my code. The first produces the right format but the second does not:

```
First output file (fileB in my code)
A,B,C
D,E,F

Second output file (fileC in my code)
A,B,
  C
D,E,
  F
```

Here is my code:

```
file1 = open ('fileA.csv', 'rt', newline = '')

shore_upstream = open('fileB.csv', 'wt', newline = '')
shore_downstream = open('fileC.csv', 'wt', newline = '')

for line in file1:
    first_comma = line.find(',')
    second_comma = line.find(',', first_comma + 1)
    start_coordinate = line [first_comma +1 : second_comma]
    start_coordinate_number = int(start_coordinate)
    end_coordinte = line [second_comma +1 :]
    end_coordinate_number = int (end_coordinte)
    upstream_start = start_coordinate_number - 2000
    downstream_end = end_coordinate_number + 2000
    upstream_start_string = str(upstream_start)
    downstring_end_string = str(downstream_end)
    upstream_shore = line[:first_comma]+','+ upstream_start_string + ',' + start_coordinate 
    shore_upstream.write(upstream_shore + '\n')
    downstream_shore = line[:first_comma]+ ','+ end_coordinte + ',' + downstring_end_string
    shore_downstream.write(downstream_shore + '\n')

file1.close()
shore_upstream.close()
shore_downstream.close()
```

By the way, I am using python 3.3.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `csv` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `end_coordinte` may contain non-decimal characters in it, and probably contains a `\n\t` at the end, resulting in that output.

The simplest solution might be to evaluate those strings as a number, and printing them back as strings.
Replace:

```
upstream_shore = line[:first_comma]+','+ upstream_start_string + ',' + start_coordinate
downstream_shore = line[:first_comma]+ ','+ end_coordinte + ',' + downstring_end_string
```

by:

```
upstream_shore = line[:first_comma]+','+ upstream_start_string + ',' + str(start_coordinate_number) 
downstream_shore = line[:first_comma]+ ','+ str(end_coordinate_number) + ',' + downstring_end_string
```

And pay attention to the `line[:first_comma]` output, as it may also contain characters you are not expecting.